# 502 errors on WordPress / nginx / php5-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I've looked through lots of other Server Fault and Google results that all have talk about generally similar situations, but I can't quite find the insight that I'm looking for. I would appreciate any help that the community can provide, and don't want anyone thinking that I didn't do an exhaustive amount of research before asking for help. I truly appreciate anyone who takes the to respond and educate me on this.

Here's the situation:

I have a Digital Ocean server with an 8 core processor, 16 GB RAM, and 160 GB SSD. The server is running WordPress on nginx + php5-fpm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I've always used Apache in the past, so this is my first foray into nginx.

Anyway, the site is running fine *but* I'm getting 502 bad gateway errors occasionally, and have had reports that users are also experience this problem on an intermittent basis. I have fairly aggressive edge caching with CloudFlare, to limit the number of hits to the actual original server.

The nginx error logs show a common problem:

```
2015/07/03 17:38:51 [error] 4283#0: *74154 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.245.xx.xx, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:
```

I'm finding that these entries correspond with the 502 scenario, but what I can't figure out is how to effective tune the php5-fpm and nginx to support the traffic.

`top` shows %Cpu(s): fluctuating between 27% and 54% during the several different times that I've been monitoring.

Memory usage also seems fine to me; here's the output from `free -h`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        15G       248M        71M       1.3G        11G
-/+ buffers/cache:       2.3G        13G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Finally, turning to the nginx configuration, based on what I read, I have the worker_processes set to 8, with 16192 worker_connections. Here's what the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` looks like:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  16192;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And here's the config from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 127.0.0.1 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my.website.com;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Final note: There are virtual hosts running on this machine too, each of which has a similar site config with fastcgi caching, and each is running WordPress.

Adding the config file for one of the vhosts, at the suggestion of @pennywise. I'm leaving my comments inline.

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache/vhostdomain levels=1:2 keys_zone=vhostdomain:100m inactive=60m;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www.vhostdomain.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.vhostdomain.com;
    server_namevhostdomain.com;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/vhostdomain.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/vhostdomain.com.error.log;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # If the URL contains the query strings params cb or clk, bypass the cache
    if ($query_string ~* "cb=|clk=") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # If the URL contains the /ad/ directory, bypass cache
    if ($request_uri ~* "/ad/") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }    

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

        fastcgi_cachevhostdomain;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;

    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }    
}
```

Adding `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` sans comments:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

Comment: You need to read your fpm logs. If nginx says unable to connect, fpm is going to be saying something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In your config you have two location blocks `\.php$`
This is most probably the culprit, combine them in one and you should be fine.

Sometimes staring long time at code/config files makes your mind misses something obvious.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @pennywise. I have, indeed, been staring at this for a while and missed that. I removed it. It's worth noting, though, that the duplicate detail doesn't exist in the vhosts, which are also seeing the issue.

Comment: You can post these configs as well in the question. If you think there is not a problem with them, you might be under DoS. I recently had such a problem on a smaller DO VPS, but I use monit to monitor services and noticed. Check your logs for someone DoS-ing site around/before the time of the error.

Comment: Thanks @pennywise. I just added the vhost config to the original question.

I'd obviously never rule a DoS out of the question, but the odd thing is that it's intermittent, and nothing seems particularly odd in the log files. A big question that I'm trying to understand is, do my config settings seem reasonable, given the hardware? Perhaps the answer is just that I need to increase to a larger VPS. I just don't know.

Comment: In general Nginx docs advise against using `if`, check this - http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
Also you might want to set up monitoring(if you don't already have), with something like munin, so if you have service like php5-fpm down, the daemon will bring it back. 
Other than that the question is pretty broad. Maybe posting and the php5-fpm will help if not to me, to someone else. It should be located in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Comment: Thanks again, @pennywise. I've added the www.conf contents to the question. I removed the comments, in the interest of brevity.

Comment: Duplicate/overlapping location blocks are not going to cause problems. Simply, the last one declared would be unreachable.